# Question about the definition of wavelet

Tags: fourier-transform, wavelet

From the definition, we will use wavelet for expanding signals the same way
Fourier series use sinusoids:

$$f(t) = \sum a_{l}ψ_l(t)$$
The definition then defines that if $ψ_l(t)$ form an orthonormal basis for the function space
then
$$a_l = \, < f(t), ψ_l(t) >$$
How is this second equation derived?
Here is the link for the definition:
[Introduction to Wavelets](https://cnx.org/contents/EQurkhlI@6.9:9Qg8uP5e@5/Introduction-to-Wavelets)

Comment: Hi William! In general, it's a good idea to include a link to the reference for definitions, as they can vary from textbook to textbook, paper to paper.

Comment: @Jdip Thank you for your reminder. I added the link to the article with the definitions listed in the question.

Comment: The question's unclear, definitions like this aren't "derived", they "are" because we say so, like "Let x=1". What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're missing.  First, it appears that the author is using $\left \langle x(t), y(t) \right \rangle$ to mean the inner product of two functions over the interval: $\left \langle x(t), y(t) \right \rangle = \int x(t) y(t) dt$.

Second, they mention the basis functions being orthonormal, but they only define the "ortho" half.  "Ortho-" is a prefix meaning "square" or "at right angles to".  In vector spaces and (I think I'm using the term right) function spaces, a pair of things are orthogonal (literally at right angles to each other) if their inner product is equal to zero.  They are ortho**normal** to one another if each one's inner product *with itself* is equal to 1 (i.e., it's length = 1).

So, if you have some set of functions $\psi_k(t)$ that are defined on an interval on the real number line, and each one is orthonormal to all the rest, and there's an infinite number of them* then you can represent *any* analytic function $f(t)$ as a weighted sum of the basis functions.  This is the source of their equation
$$f(t) = \sum_k a_k \psi_k(t). \tag 1$$

Note that if you choose $\psi_k(t)$ correctly you've just rediscovered the Fourier series -- any sort of transform that uses basis functions like this is a generalization of the Fourier series.

Now, all of the babbling so far has been to get you ready for this: if you start with $$\left \langle f(t), \psi_k(t) \right \rangle \tag 2$$ and substitute in (1), you get
$$\left \langle \sum_k a_k \psi_k(t), \psi_k(t) \right \rangle. \tag 3$$

Keeping in mind that $\langle \rangle$ is shorthand for an integration, you can switch the order of the summation and the integration:

$$\left \langle f(t), \psi_k(t) \right \rangle = a_k \sum_j \left \langle \psi_k(t), \psi_j(t) \right \rangle. \tag 4$$

Long story short, every instance inside the sum in (4) where $j \ne k$ is equal to zero, and for $j = k$ it is equal to one.  So you end up with
$$\left \langle f(t), \psi_k(t) \right \rangle = a_k, \tag 4$$ and the page's assertion is proved**.

* Hopefully I have all these conditions right

** Engineer-proved.  I'm sure I'm cutting mathematical corners here.